# Actionscript 3 Convert a MovieClip to Video file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, runtime

I have a movieclip that include video and animated movieclip object which user load the image inside it. I need to convert the movieclip as video file at runtime. Because I want to open final video on mobile device also.

My first aim is convert the movieclip as a video file. Is there any way to convert it or an alternative way to open swf on mobile devices?

I searched on the internet but I can not find any solution about that.

Comment: Can't you do a file > Export > As movie? or screen cap the MC?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that at runtime in AS3. Maybe with some ANE it might be possible. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: To open SWF on mobile you'll have to compile as app instead of trying to run SWF within mobile browser. As for making runtime output as video... well thats video encoding and you'll have to write your own MP4 / H.264 encoder in AS3 and also pay MPEG for the rights. FFMPEG on mobile could be an option (ANE related). Google for **AS3 AIR using ffmpeg on Android** for example and if any results make sense thats your options. Usually though no-one asks this question, you should have known/checked how to do this video-output part before even starting...